# Possessive pronoun drops in fiction

Tags: pronouns

Assuming the reader knows who is being referred to, what do you think is the effect on the reader when possessive pronouns are dropped in fiction. For example:

> Brown hair is pulled back into a tight bun, giving cheeks a stretched look.

Seems to me (note the subject pronoun drop), the result is that the reader focuses more on the narrator than the character being discussed.  All reactions will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried asking this question in [writers.se]?

Comment: Haven't tried Writers.  Will do.  Thanks for the tip, TrevorD.

Answer (score 1):

The reader focuses more on the writing, thinking "???", than either the character or the narrator.